# How to Block Duplicate Transactions on CyberSource REST API

Tags: rest, cybersource

The CyberSource payments system seems to have a method of preventing duplicate transactions, as [covered here](https://support.cybersource.com/s/article/How-do-I-block-duplicate-orders):

> This functionality looks at the Merchant Reference Number (MRN) of successful orders submitted within the last 15 minutes of a previous order, and blocks any duplicate transactions submitted with the same MRN.

and [here](https://developer.cybersource.com/library/documentation/dev_guides/Secure_Acceptance_Hosted_Checkout/html/Topics/Reason_Codes.htm):

> Reason Code 104: The access_key and transaction_uuid fields for this authorization request match the access_key and transaction_uuid fields of another authorization request that you sent within the past 15 minutes.

Although it's obvious you need to use `transaction_uuid` for earlier APIs such as KVP, it's not clear which field to use for the [REST API](https://developer.cybersource.com/api-reference-assets/index.html#payments_payments_process-a-payment).

Answer (score 1):

Use the `clientReferenceInformation` > `transactionId` field.  You can see this in [the playground](https://developer.cybersource.com/api-reference-assets/index.html#payments_payments_process-a-payment) with a request body like:

```
{
  "clientReferenceInformation": {
    "code": "TC50171_3",
    "transactionId": "465465411adfasdfsdf"
  },
  "processingInformation": {
    "reconciliationId": "1234"
  },
  "paymentInformation": {
    "card": {
      "number": "4111111111111111",
      "expirationMonth": "12",
      "expirationYear": "2031"
    }
  },
  "orderInformation": {
    "amountDetails": {
      "totalAmount": "102.21",
      "currency": "USD"
    },
    "billTo": {
      "firstName": "John",
      "lastName": "Doe",
      "address1": "1 Market St",
      "locality": "san francisco",
      "administrativeArea": "CA",
      "postalCode": "94105",
      "country": "US",
      "email": "test@cybs.com",
      "phoneNumber": "4158880000"
    }
  }
}
```

If you include the same `transactionId` twice, the backend will tell you <del>to get bent</del> `INVALID_DATA`.  I would actually expect it to return `DUPLICATE_REQUEST` as a reason, (it's in their list of possible responses) but this is better than a poke in the eye with a sharp stick.

Comment: Reported the incorrect response value here: https://github.com/CyberSource/cybersource-rest-client-node/issues/45